# php form onsubmit event loading new page with value of 0

Tags: php, forms, onsubmit

I am totally new to all things php but I have managed to piece meal together the below form. But for some reason that I don't understand, everytime I hit the submit button it goes to a new page with a value of 0 on it. Here is the page
http://upcycledonline.com/test/Site/myform2.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit"){
        $errorMessage = "";

        if(empty($_POST['formEmail'])){
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your email</li>";
        }

        $varEmail = ($_POST['formEmail'].mysql_real_escape_string);

        //$varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];

        if(empty($errorMessage)){

            $db = mysql_connect("server","id","password");
            if(!$db)
                die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
            mysql_select_db("tableName" ,$db);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('$varEmail')";
            mysql_query($sql);


            //$sql = ("INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('%s')".mysql_real_escape_string($varEmail));
            //$results = mysql_query($sql);
            //$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (emails)" 
                   //. "VALUES ('{$varEmail}');
            //mysql_query($sql);

            // echo "Details added";
            // $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
        }

        //header("Location: thankyou.html");
        exit();
    }


    function PrepSQL($value){
        // Stripslashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        // Quote
        //this is how I should be doing the escape thing
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        return($value);
    }
?>
```

and here is the form

```
<?php
   if(!empty($errorMessage)){
       echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
       echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
   }
?>

<form id="emailForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
      method="post" onSubmit="alert('Thank you. Your email has been added.')">
    <label for='formEmail'>Sign up to be notified when we go live!</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="formEmail" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varEmail;?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: These are separate files?  
In case they are, you would have to change the form action to point to the second file. (the one receiving your data).
If the code is in one file, this is not the solution.

Comment: The link you provided gives me "You forgot to enter your email" (no `<li>` tag). The code you have does not reflect what the URL points to.

Comment: This really isn't a question is it? more like you're asking someone to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in one file, it still has a few issues.

Instead of:
$varEmail = ($_POST['formEmail'].mysql_real_escape_string);

Try:
$varEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formEmail']);

This should bring the code to the mysql part, and then it will just exit.

The header command can be used to redirect to a "thank you" page, or just echo if success or fail.

Then look for data in your database. :)

BTW:
You almost had it in the PrepSql function, but it is not used.
So you could do: $varEmail = PrepSql($_POST['formEmail']);
Mind the extra '' though.

And cheers for learning to escape data early on! :)

Edit:

You might get an error on the input line in the form where it says `<?$varEmail;?>`...
There you are using "short tag", meaning you skip the "php" in:
`<?php echo $myVar;?>`. Also missing "echo".

You can just remove that part - since you get the value from user input.

This echoes my input on my machine (commented out sql for the test):

```
<?php

if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
    $errorMessage = "";

    if(empty($_POST['formEmail'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your email</li>";
    }

    $varEmail = PrepSql($_POST['formEmail']);


    //$varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {

        /*$db= mysql_connect("server","id","password");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("tableName" ,$db);*/

        echo $varEmail;

        //$sql = "INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('$varEmail')";
        //mysql_query($sql);


        //$sql = ("INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('%s')".mysql_real_escape_string($varEmail));
        //$results = mysql_query($sql);

        //$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (emails)" 
        //. "VALUES ('{$varEmail}');
        //mysql_query($sql);

        // echo "Details added";
        // $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
    }

    //header("Location: thankyou.html");
    exit();

}


function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    // Quote
    //this is how I should be doing the escape thing
    //$value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

    return($value);
}




if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
{
   echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
   echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
}
?>

<form id="emailForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"     method="post" onSubmit="alert('Thank you. Your email has been added.')">

            <label for='formEmail'>Sign up to be notified when we go live!</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="formEmail" maxlength="50" />

        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: I would love to do what you have mentioned with the Real_escape and have in fact tried it multiple times but continue to get error messages about system 111 and could not connect to host etc. I have read that this is a result of not establishing a connection before the code executes but I thought I had that done.

Comment: You test your code by using echo to show you content of variables. You can also use exit() or die() after the code you want to test, then move it further down as things work. This will help you find the first errors without the next ones being in the way :)